# C# datagridview find and get value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have some text and a `datagridview` with 5 columns. How can I find this text in the first column and get values from other columns in the same row?

Comment: It sounds like you put data directly into the DataGridView.  If you know that, you should know how to get it back out.  Post your best attempt so we have *something* to work with

Comment: DataGridViews have a `Rows` property. From memory, each row has a `Cells` property. Each cell has a `Value` property. The rows and cells properties are both arrays that you can walk by index. After that, you just write some code

Comment: What do you use a datasource? Do you use a DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code lines will give you the datagridview row index for the value:

```
String searchValue = "somestring";
int rowIndex = -1;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
    {
        rowIndex = row.Index;
        break;
    }
}
```

then you can do:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be :

```
List<string> Values = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows)
{
  if (row["firstColumn"].ToString() == yourText)
  {
    Values.Add(row["firstColumn"].ToString());
    Values.Add(row["secondColumn"].ToString());
    Values.Add(row["thirdColumn"].ToString());
    Values.Add(row["fourthColumn"].ToString());
    Values.Add(row["fifthColumn"].ToString());
   }
}
```